# Colorbox.js inline content won't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

I am trying to use the inline content function with colorbox.js but it just doesn't seem to show up when using the inline function, although all other functions are working properly. I am using the unedited JS and CSS files. Here's is the code:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", transition:'none'});
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="inline" href="#inline_content"><li><h1>Content</h1></li></a>
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff; color:#000;'>   
<p>Hello! This is content </p> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` options requires you to also set the `href` option.

> If true, content from the current document can be displayed by passing
>   the href property a jQuery selector, or jQuery object.

```
// Using a selector:
$("#inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#myForm"});
// Using a jQuery object: var $form = $("#myForm");
$("#inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:$form});
```

[See the documentation](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

Comment: I've seen pages not using that with it working. I've tried changing the JS to   $(document).ready(function(){
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", transition:'none', href:"#inline_content"});
}); and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the href.

For example:

```html
<a href="#myForm" class="inline">
```

Then, you could have this:

```js
$(".inline").colorbox({
inline: true,
width: "50"
});
```